# Transform Input XML to an output XML using templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have an input XML which I am trying to trasnform into a more structured XML output. Below are few conditions for structuring the data -

1.If `Report_Entry` node doesn't have a `Employee_ID` child element, then discard whole `Report_Entry` node.

2.If `Employee_ID` node exists then merge all the `Report_Entry` nodes with same `Employee_ID` value. Every Report_Entry node will have details of either Child or Spouse. This is determined based on `Relationship` node value. If Relationship is Spouse then add a new child node Spouse and insert the dependent details (name, SSN, DoB and COBRA details). If Relationship is Child then add a new Dependent node and insert the dependent details into it.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/DNU_CR_Dependents_COBRA_Records">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Dependent_Name></wd:Dependent_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-10-11</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-10</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Spouse - Divorce or legal separation of the covered employee</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
            <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - Delta Dental PPO BREG</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
        </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-10-13</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-11</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Spouse - Divorce or legal separation of the covered employee</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
            <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Medical-US - Local 32</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
        </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>1003413</wd:Employee_ID>
        <wd:Worker_Name>Amy Bush</wd:Worker_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Name>Matthew Bush</wd:Dependent_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Matthew</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Bush</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>1970-12-07</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
        <wd:Relationship>Spouse</wd:Relationship>
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-10-02</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-01</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Spouse - Divorce or legal separation of the covered employee</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
            <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
        </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>1003413</wd:Employee_ID>
        <wd:Worker_Name>Amy Bush</wd:Worker_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Name>Katherine Bush</wd:Dependent_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Katherine</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Bush</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>1999-12-07</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-10-02</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-01</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Dependent Children - Loss of dependent child status under the plan rules</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
            <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
        </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>2001679</wd:Employee_ID>
        <wd:Worker_Name>Phuong-Thao Li (On Leave)</wd:Worker_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Name>Audrie Li</wd:Dependent_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Audrie</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Li</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>2011-10-19</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
        <wd:Relationship>Child</wd:Relationship>
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-11-03</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-11-01</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Dependent Children - Loss of dependent child status under the plan rules</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
            <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
        </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>2001679</wd:Employee_ID>
        <wd:Worker_Name>Phuong-Thao Li (On Leave)</wd:Worker_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Name>Colton Li</wd:Dependent_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Colton</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Li</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>2009-10-29</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
        <wd:Relationship>Child</wd:Relationship>
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-10-20</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-10</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Employee - Leave of Absence (LTD)</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
            <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
        </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>2001679</wd:Employee_ID>
        <wd:Worker_Name>Phuong-Thao Li (On Leave)</wd:Worker_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Name>Kaelyn Li</wd:Dependent_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Kaelyn</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Li</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>2004-09-25</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
        <wd:Relationship>Child</wd:Relationship>
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-11-01</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-20</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Dependent Children - Loss of dependent child status under the plan rules</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
            <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
        </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>2001679</wd:Employee_ID>
        <wd:Worker_Name>Phuong-Thao Li (On Leave)</wd:Worker_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Name>Eliza Li</wd:Dependent_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Eliza</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Li</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>1988-11-01</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
        <wd:Relationship>Spouse</wd:Relationship>
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-09-06</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-09-03</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Employee - Leave of Absence (LTD)</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
            <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Medical-US - Local 501 HMO</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
        </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-09-06</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-09-01</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Spouse - Divorce or legal separation of the covered employee</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
            <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
        </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>2001679</wd:Employee_ID>
        <wd:Worker_Name>Phuong-Thao Li (On Leave)</wd:Worker_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Name>Andria Li</wd:Dependent_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Andria</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Li</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>2000-11-01</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
        <wd:Relationship>Child</wd:Relationship>
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-10-05</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-02</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Dependent Children - Loss of dependent child status under the plan rules</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
            <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
        </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>9100637</wd:Employee_ID>
        <wd:Worker_Name>Cheri Holtzworth (Retired - Active)</wd:Worker_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Name>Annie Holtzworth</wd:Dependent_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Annie</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Holtzworth</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
        <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>1989-10-04</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
        <wd:Relationship>Spouse</wd:Relationship>
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-10-29</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-28</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
            <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Employee - Death of Employee</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
            <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Healthcare FSA - Empire FSA</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
        </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

I want the output in this format -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/DNU_CR_Dependents_COBRA_Records">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>1003413</wd:Employee_ID>
        <wd:Spouse>
            <wd:Worker_Name>Amy Bush</wd:Worker_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Name>Matthew Bush</wd:Dependent_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Matthew</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Bush</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>1970-12-07</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
                <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-10-02</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-01</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Spouse - Divorce or legal separation of the covered
                    employee</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
                <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO
                    Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
            </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
        </wd:Spouse>
        <wd:Dependent>
            <wd:Worker_Name>Amy Bush</wd:Worker_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Name>Katherine Bush</wd:Dependent_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Katherine</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Bush</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>1999-12-07</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
                <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-10-02</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-01</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Dependent Children - Loss of dependent child status
                    under the plan rules</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
                <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO
                    Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
            </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
        </wd:Dependent>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>2001679</wd:Employee_ID>
        <wd:Dependent>
            <wd:Worker_Name>Phuong-Thao Li (On Leave)</wd:Worker_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Name>Audrie Li</wd:Dependent_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Audrie</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Li</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>2011-10-19</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
                <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-11-03</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-11-01</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Dependent Children - Loss of dependent child status
                    under the plan rules</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
                <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO
                    Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
            </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
        </wd:Dependent>
        <wd:Dependent>
            <wd:Worker_Name>Phuong-Thao Li (On Leave)</wd:Worker_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Name>Colton Li</wd:Dependent_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Colton</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Li</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
                <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-10-20</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-10</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Employee - Leave of Absence
                    (LTD)</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
                <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO
                    Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
            </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
        </wd:Dependent>
        <wd:Dependent>
            <wd:Worker_Name>Phuong-Thao Li (On Leave)</wd:Worker_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Name>Kaelyn Li</wd:Dependent_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Kaelyn</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Li</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>2004-09-25</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
                <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-11-01</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-20</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Dependent Children - Loss of dependent child status
                    under the plan rules</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
                <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO
                    Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
            </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
        </wd:Dependent>
        <wd:Spouse>
            <wd:Worker_Name>Phuong-Thao Li (On Leave)</wd:Worker_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Name>Eliza Li</wd:Dependent_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Eliza</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Li</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>1988-11-01</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
                <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-09-06</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-09-03</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Employee - Leave of Absence
                    (LTD)</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
                <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Medical-US - Local 501 HMO</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
            </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
                <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-09-06</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-09-01</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Spouse - Divorce or legal separation of the covered
                    employee</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
                <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO
                    Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
            </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
        </wd:Spouse>
        <wd:Dependent>
            <wd:Worker_Name>Phuong-Thao Li (On Leave)</wd:Worker_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Name>Andria Li</wd:Dependent_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Andria</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Li</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>2000-11-01</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
                <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-10-05</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-02</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Dependent Children - Loss of dependent child status
                    under the plan rules</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
                <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Dental-US - MetLife Dental PPO
                    Hawaii</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
            </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
        </wd:Dependent>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>9100637</wd:Employee_ID>
        <wd:Spouse>
            <wd:Worker_Name>Cheri Holtzworth (Retired - Active)</wd:Worker_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Name>Annie Holtzworth</wd:Dependent_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_First_Name>Annie</wd:Dependent_First_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Last_Name>Holtzworth</wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
            <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>1989-10-04</wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
            <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
                <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>2015-10-29</wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>2015-10-28</wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
                <wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>Employee - Death of
                    Employee</wd:Dependent_Eligibility_Reason>
                <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>Healthcare FSA - Empire FSA</wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
            </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
        </wd:Spouse>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

I was trying to figure out how to use templates and have created an XSLT but not able to code the correct logic for getting the desired output -

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/DNU_CR_Dependents_COBRA_Records">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
        <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/DNU_CR_Dependents_COBRA_Records"><wd:Report_Entry><xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Entry"/>
            </wd:Report_Entry>
        </wd:Report_Data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
        <wd:Dependent><xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Worker_Name"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Dependent_Name"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Dependent_First_Name"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Dependent_Last_Name"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range"/>
        </wd:Dependent>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range">
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range><xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date"/>
        </wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
        <wd:Report_Entry><xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Employee_ID"/>
            <wd:Spouse><xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Worker_Name"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Dependent_Name"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Dependent_First_Name"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Dependent_Last_Name"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range"/>
            </wd:Spouse>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date">
        <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date><xsl:value-of select="."/></wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Employee_ID">
        <wd:Employee_ID><xsl:value-of select="."/></wd:Employee_ID>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Worker_Name">
        <wd:Worker_Name><xsl:value-of select="."/></wd:Worker_Name>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Dependent_Name">
        <wd:Dependent_Name><xsl:value-of select="."/></wd:Dependent_Name>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Dependent_First_Name">
        <wd:Dependent_First_Name><xsl:value-of select="."/></wd:Dependent_First_Name>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Dependent_Last_Name">
        <wd:Dependent_Last_Name><xsl:value-of select="."/></wd:Dependent_Last_Name>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth">
        <wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth><xsl:value-of select="."/></wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date">
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date><xsl:value-of select="."/></wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date">
        <wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date><xsl:value-of select="."/></wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Dependent_Qualifying_Event_Date">
        <wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date><xsl:value-of select="."/></wd:Dependent_COBRA_Eligible_Date>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan">
        <wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan><xsl:value-of select="."/></wd:Dependent_Benefit_Plan>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please select either XSLT1.0 or 2.0 - not both.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - i have removed xslt 1.0 as xslt 2.0 is recommended for my application. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.If Report_Entry node doesn't have a Employee_ID child element, then discard whole Report_Entry node.
>
> 2.If Employee_ID node exists then merge all the Report_Entry nodes with same Employee_ID value. Every Report_Entry node will have details
>   of either Child or Spouse. This is determined based on Relationship
>   node value. If Relationship is Spouse then add a new child node Spouse
>   and insert the dependent details (name, SSN, DoB and COBRA details).
>   If Relationship is Child then add a new Dependent node and insert the
>   dependent details into it.

AFAICT, all these requirements can be met by:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/DNU_CR_Dependents_COBRA_Records">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry[wd:Employee_ID]" group-by="wd:Employee_ID">
            <wd:Report_Entry>
                <xsl:copy-of select="wd:Employee_ID"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
             </wd:Report_Entry>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
    <xsl:element name="wd:{if (wd:Relationship='Spouse') then 'Spouse' else 'Dependent'}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Worker_Name | wd:Dependent_Name | wd:Dependent_First_Name | wd:Dependent_Last_Name | wd:Dependent_Date_of_Birth | wd:Dependent_COBRA_Records_within_Range"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:

> Every Report_Entry node will have details of either Child or Spouse.

In your example, Katherine Bush is neither Child nor Spouse - yet you have her listed as a Dependent. I took that to mean that *any* Report_Entry that isn't a Spouse is a Dependent.